# Как настроить тунелирование трафика только внутри VPN-сети?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, vpn, openvpn

Доброго времени суток.

Я настроил сервер OpenVPТ на Ubuntu 20.4. Создал клиентский конфиг.
Подключившись с помощью этого конфига, например на своем ноутбуке и зайдя на google.com, маршрут будет лежать через VPN-сеть, в чем я могу убедиться, зайдя на whoer.net и увидев адрес VPN, а не адрес моего домашнего провайдера. Как мне избавиться от этого?

Мне нужно разрешить только трафик внутри VPN-сети, весь остальной траффик клиента должен идти по обычному маршруту.

Конгиф серевера:

```
;local a.b.c.d

port 1194

;proto tcp
proto udp

;dev tap
dev tun

;dev-node MyTap

ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh.pem
tls-auth ta.key 0

;dh dh2048.pem

;topology subnet

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt

;server-bridge 10.8.0.4 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.50 10.8.0.100

;server-bridge

;push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
;push "route 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0"

;client-config-dir ccd
;route 192.168.40.128 255.255.255.248

;client-config-dir ccd
;route 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.252

;learn-address ./script

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"

client-to-client

;duplicate-cn

keepalive 10 120

tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret

cipher AES-256-CBC

;compress lz4-v2
;push "compress lz4-v2"

;comp-lzo

;max-clients 100

;user nobody
;group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log

;log         /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
;log-append  /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log

verb 3

;mute 20

explicit-exit-notify 1
```

Comment: а можете показать конфиг сервера? возможно там есть изменение дефолтного гейтвея или роутов

Comment: Да, конечно. Добавил конфиг в первый пост.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Закомментируйте/удалите эту строку:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

В дефолтной конфигурации есть небольшое описание этой опции:

> If enabled, this directive will configure
> all clients to redirect their default
> network gateway through the VPN, causing
> all IP traffic such as web browsing and
> and DNS lookups to go through the VPN

Также если вы настраивали `iptables` подобным правилом, его можно тоже удалить, т.к. теперь в нем нет необходимости (но и изменение серверной конфигурации должно хватить):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, это сработало!
Зря я наверное коментарии в конфиге все удалил :)